# Configuring Apache Document Root for Eclipse Workspaces with PHP

Tags: php, eclipse, apache, apache2

I've set up PHP and Apache for my Snow Leopard machine using these [instructions](http://maestric.com/doc/mac/apache_php_mysql_snow_leopard) I can change Document Root in httpd.conf such that I can run php files from different local directories.  However, when I set it to the the location of my Eclipse workspace, I get "Forbidden - You don't have permission to access / on this server"

I'd like to be able to use the Eclipse New PHP Project to "Create a new project in workspace" instead of creating a directory somewhere else and using "Create project at existing location..."

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify corresponding `<Directory path>` directive. You already have this directive for previous DocumentRoot, so just change path in there to your current document root.

Comment: I changed both Document Root and Directory Path. As I said, I was successful at setting it to different directories.  However, there's something special about the Eclipse workspace directory that I'm missing.

Comment: hmm, I guess you checked Eclipse workspace directory permissions. Can you post httpd.conf contents, with an example of working local directory?

Comment: Permissions was the key to the solution.  The Eclipse workspace permissions were correct, but its parent directory - ~/Documents/ - was 700.  Making the Documents folder 755 solved it.